# Applying jQuery UI CSS classes to elements manually causes the JS to misbehave

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, class

Greetings,

So I am trying to manually apply the jQuery CSS classes to my elements, so that users do not have a 'flash' as my javascript styles everything, and so users without JavaScript enabled get to see the purdyness.

So here is an example of a button. I have applied all the classes the `.button()` call would add, and structured my markup in the same way.

```
<button id="my-button" type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">Doit!</span>
</button>
```

This looks great on its own! Of course it has no hover styles etc, but that's expected.

Then I apply my Javascript:

```
$('#my-button').button();
```

jQuery UI doesn't seem to be aware of the existing classes/markup, and it turns my lovely button into this:

```
<button id="my-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text">Doit!</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

So finally my question:

**How can I apply the CSS classes manually/without javascript, yet still use the javascript functions to add the interaction functionality?**

edit: ok so the markup generated by `.button()` isn't exactly what I posted there ^^ that was a `.button(` call with an icon parameter. The issue is the same though, with a simple .button() call it just wraps everything inside a `<span class="ui-button-text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first clear the button and then run the .button() to recreate your ui-button

```
$('#my-button').html(function(){return $(this).text();}).button({ icons: {primary:'ui-icon-plus'}});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHaxd/1/

Comment: That seems really really obvious now :/ Thanks!

Comment: It also seems like a lot of work. Surely jQuery UI should be updated to handle this scenario and not add the extra `<span>` elements? This is what I would expect in any case.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a known issue ( [Button: support pre-rendered markup](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5758) ), and as you and I both would expect, the extra `<span>` elements will hopefully one day not actually be generated :)

Comment: Though, that bug was opened a year ago... go up vote it! It's currently at 0 votes (it was at -1 before I voted for it, which is kinda disappointing).

Comment: @elwyn thank you too for confirming that it wasn't just me :D and for voting :)